# Book series with humans fighting bug aliens. They create an AI that decides to help them. Book includes time-travel

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I'm looking for a series I read a few years ago and I can't remember the author or title

Humanity is fighting a race of bug aliens that eat everything. They create sentient AI by mistake but they decided to help humanity. The AI create time travel and at the end of the book series the aliens invaded Earth and killed everyone. Then the AI go back in time and save everyone because they figured out where and when the bugs were made then they come back to Earth and no one has any idea. There is also no USA and Canada and Mexico it's all the north American union and there is a law in the book that makes it I illegal speak about your religion unless they share your faith and u are at church.

Comment: While I appreciate that you want to "bump" your question, it's better to do so by adding useful details rather than lowering the quality of the question title.

Comment: Why not have a look through [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if there's anything else you can add.

Answer (score 8):

Bit of a long shot, but could you be thinking of [*Einstein's Bridge*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?156401+c)?  There are a number of differences, but the general shape is the same.

**Similarities:**

- Bug aliens.
- The aliens end up destroying the world and are eventually defeated by the main characters traveling back in time and preventing them from ever getting started.

**Differences:**

- Single book, not a series.
- The time travel is facilitated not by AI, but by another alien race that makes contact (although secretly) at around the same time as the bug aliens.

If you're sure it was AI that ended up saving the day, then this isn't it.  But if it could possibly be a race of benevolent aliens rather than AI, then it might be worth a look.

Comment: Not it but this sounds like a good read

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like the [Synchronicity War](https://www.goodreads.com/series/120935-the-synchronicity-war) series by Dietmar Wehr.

Similarities:
Humans create AI. 
AI is beneficial.
Time travel is supplied by alien race (who doesn't really care about humans but who really want to save an unrelated species who will be killed after humans fall)
The bug aliens kidnap live creatures to use as incubators.

Differences:
I can't remember whether the AI was created by accident.

Additional:
The bug aliens are not the first alien species to fight humanity.
Weaponry is described as MkX drones, where the lower numbers are dumbfire impact missiles.
The AIs bond with the main character, referring to him as the CAG (in this context meaning Commander Autonomous Group)

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a nice first answer though may I suggest you add two answers, one for each series? It's generally considered better to have one id per answer so it's clear what people are voting on.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I suggest [Ian Douglas' *Star Carrier* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61745-star-carrier)

Similarity:

- There is AI (One large AI, Konstantin, on earths moon.)
- Konstantin uses memetic engineering to create a religion called Starlight.
- Earth is under attack by various alien species.
- The attack on Earth is stopped when a portal through time is discovered, taking the carrier group to the home system of the main antagonists.
- Religion is forbidden in public, under a system called the 'White Covenant'.

Differences:

There are bug aliens, but they are not voracious. In the first book there are the Agletsch, resembling giant flies, who are 'neutral'. They act as traders and diplomats.

Additional:

Main character in the first book is mocked for being Prim (primitive).
Later he gets a new nickname (Sandy) for unorthodox use of sand in relativistic combat.
In the first book, earth is under attack by a species of standing worm (tentacle?), which only survive in pairs. When they speak, a third voice is created between them.